# Creating a loadingscreen using CALayer

Tags: iphone

I want to add a simple loading-screen to my app while it is loading several content from a webserver to inform the user.
To get round corners and a nice border i'm using a CALayer Object.
But when i want to add content to this layer, is doesn't work.
I can only add Images and other CALayer objects, but i want to add a UILabel or a UIView.
Is this possible? I checked some tutorials and apple documents but i cant find a solution.
Is there a simple solution to fix that problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every view in UIKit is backed by a layer so you can have the power of both worlds. Use a UIView with UILabel for the text and set the corner radius of the views backing layer via the layer property

```
myView.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0;
```